# Codeigniter TCPDF (multiple pdf with different data)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

This is a working code for generating multiple pdf

```
   <?php
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Invoice');
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(10);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(10);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Invoice');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    foreach($invoice as $row){
        $body='HTML 
        XXXXXXX
 XXXXXXX 
 XXXXXXX
foreach($invoicedata as $rowdata){
 XXXXXXX
}
        Table';}

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->writeHTML($body, true, false, true, false, '');
        $pdf->lastPage();

        //$pdf->Write(5, $tnc);
    }

    $pdf->Output('InvoceOutput'.'\.pdf', 'I' );
    ?>
```

What is the code generated
Multiple PDF with different data.

Current Problem

> When in INVOICEID consist of INVOICEDATA (Invoice data consist of
>   multiple row of data but might have same InvoiceID)  so that when the
>   pdf is generated , it generated 4 DIFFERENT PDF page with 1 row of "INVOICE
>   DATA" each

Example:

> InvoiceID 1 consist of 4 InvoiceDataID  TCPDF will generate : 4X PDF page
>   with 4X different InvoiceData

What i want:

> When have 4 InvoiceDataID in  1 InvoiceDataID  wanted it to generate 1
>   PDF ONLY with 4 InvoiceData

Comment: 4 Pages * my bad

Comment: But ,  i need it to able to create multiple page,  as user can choose multiple "INVOICEID" , the problem right now is when the invoiceID consist of 3 InvoiceData, it will create 3x PDF page that have same invoiceID , but in the 3 PDF file that have generated , it only consist (1x ROW of data,  thats why it generated 3x pdf page)